# c++ assigning Base class to Derived

Tags: c++

Why this won't compile? What am I missing?

```
class Base
{
    public:
        Base() : data(0) { }
    protected:
        int data;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    public:
        Derived() : Base() { }
        Derived& operator=(const Base& _base)
        {
            data = _base.data; // protected member Base::data is not accessible through a "Base" pointer or object.
        }
};
```

Why is that, since data member has protected visibility (so that derived classes can access it).

Comment: `protected` doesn't mean you can access the member from any `Base`, but only from `Derived::Base` - a `Base` base class subobject of `Derived` object. There might be another class, say `X`, derived from `Base`, that uses `data` differently than `Derived` does. `Derived` shouldn't be allowed to mess with the internals of another, unrelated class.

Comment: What you should do to fix your code is to delegate to `Base::operator=`, rather than accessing `Base` members directly.

Comment: Can't you use a `friend` function?